# Trying to create multisig account for NEM on local machine but getting error

Tags: javascript, html, nem

Hello Everyone I am trying to make plugin from Buildfire to be bale to create NEM account and to change it into multisig account using local network (ei localhost)
Here are the code snippets for the required things I would like to ask weather there is an issue in making of JSON missing bits in the json or any other errors I need to look up, I have tried to look up error and it's solution but met with no results. The error I get is :

> "error: "Internal Server Error" message: "expected value for property
>   transaction, but none was found" status: 500"

```
let done = $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:7890/account/generate"
    }).done(function (data) {
        /// check you have data to report on
        ///if (data && data.list && data.list.length) {
            /// fill in the UI with the new data

        var report = data;
        PubKey = report.publicKey;
        PKey = report.privateKey;
        $('#address').text("Created Account");
            $('#balance').text(report.address);
            $('#summary').text(report.privateKey);
            $('#vested').text(report.publicKey)
        ///}
    });

var date = new Date();
            var TS = date.getTime();
            var xyz = {
                xyz: JSON.stringify({
                    "transaction":
                            {
                                "timeStamp": TS, ///needs to be changed to current timestamp from creating of account
                                "fee": 20, ///have to check
                                "type": 4097,
                                "deadline": TS + 30000, ///need to be changed
                                "version": -1744830462, /// main(real) network 1744830465,
                                "signer": PubKey,
                                "modifications": [
                                    {
                                        "modificationType": 1,
                                        "cosignatoryAccount": PbKey
                                    }
                                ],
                                "minCosignatories" : {
                                    "relativeChange": 1
                                }
                            },
                    "privateKey": PKey
                })
            };

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:7890/transaction/prepare-announce",{
                method : 'POST',
                headers : {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body : JSON.stringify(xyz)
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
                    .then(function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }).catch (function (error) {
                        console.log('Request failed', error);
                    });
```

Comment: information is less; hence do try for `var xyz={}; xyz["transcation"] = {{transactionObject}}`

Answer (score 0):

did you try normal transaction?
It looks you don't sign your transaction.
and DON'T FETCH YOUR PRIVATE KEY ON NETWORK.